# Blender Fuzzy Camera Rendering Problem

Tags: rendering, camera

I am rendering a documentary project and the sampling size is really high for each image. All the images rendered don't look fuzzy but when I combine them together for a film for some reason they look fuzzy when the camera moves. What do I do to make it so it doesn't look fuzzy when the camera move?

Comment: Can you upload an example video? It is hard to be sure of what you mean otherwise.

Comment: I just joined this site and this might sound nooby but how do I upload a video to show you?

Comment: Well, you could record a GIF with a program like LICEcap and attach it like an image, or you could use youTube and post a link in the question

Comment: Okay, I will send a link to a zip file download in a sec and it will have a quick scene example. In this scene you will notice the golden picture frame being fuzzy and part of the wall behind it.

Comment: Nevermind the zip file, the zip file was too large so I will just upload it to YouTube and send you the link when it finishes.

Comment: It is still processing but when it finishes uploading the YouTube video should be here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFK8hmKUXw8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Alright, I'll check it later

Comment: Okay it is finished, make sure to watch on 1080 to be able to see the fuzzy. For some reason it is more difficult to see the fuzzy on YouTube but if you look closely u can see it in picture frame area and the wooden wall behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to animate the Seed under Render Settings:

[image: Seed]

You can do this by hovering over it and pressing <kbd>I</kbd>, and then moving some frames, changing the value, and again pressing <kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: What is the seed? What does it exactly do? Thanks for the help so far btw.

Comment: @AustinH. I included a pic. Basically what it does is change the pattern for light rays I think. If you want in-depth info on what the seed does mechanically, then try Google.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise the seed can be animated withot the need of keyframes by clicking on the timer icon  to the right of the value slider